# Slather:only generating unit test results not the UI tests

Tags: swift, jenkins, xcode7

I'm working on **Xcode project**(swift language).I'm trying to generate coverage report using **Slather**.But Slather only generating **unit test results** but not **UI test results**.

```
slather coverage --html --scheme "Myscheme"  --output-directory "coverage/reports" --workspace abc.xcworkspace --input-format profdata --build-directory "/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" --source-directory . abc.xcodeproj
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will try to generate report after run UI without CLI then slather also should work fine. So the issue is about test coverage does not count properly while UI test run from CLI. [More info.](https://github.com/nakiostudio/xcov/issues/22#issuecomment-232014641)

upd: [It was fixed](https://github.com/iwllyu/UITestCoverageBug) in Xcode 9.